# My icons, mouse pointer etc are small on in Gnome on Ubuntu 14.04. How can I fix this?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, ubuntu-14.04, docky

My mouse pointer and toolbar icons (quit, minimize, maximize) are really small in Gnome on Ubuntu 14.04:

[image: Desktop screenshot]

..even after I set the scaling factor as:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2.0
```

The fonts and contents of windows, as well as the desktop icons are fine.

I have docky installed too, which shows very small icons.